# install vncserver without yum on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, yum

can anybody describe me how to install vncserver on Oracle Linux without yum?

(yum does not work because it is a pre-built appliance - timeouts all the time)

Answer (score 1):

> yum does not work because it is a pre-built appliance - timeouts all the time

Sounds improbable - maybe you just haven't [configured the repositories](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linux/yum-repository-setup-085606.html) / not configured any routes to the repositories.

But you could just [download the rpms](http://rpm.pbone.net/) and [install them yourself](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server) (IIRC, RH, Oracle and Centos use the same version numbering, the "unbreakable" Oracle kernel is *supposed* to be compatible with the RH kernel). But you'll need to manage [the dependencies](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17009207/dir/centos_5/com/vnc-server-4.1.2-14.el5_6.6.i386.rpm.html) yourself.